# Is there any way to check if a class is within another class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So say I wanted to check if square[6] is in row[2]. How would I do this? I want to be able to tell if two squares are within the same row.

```
<!--Row 1-->
<div class = "row">
    <!--Square 1-->
    <div class = "square" onclick="clicked(0,0)"></div>
    <!--Square 2-->
    <div class = "square" onclick="clicked(1,0)"></div>
    <!--Square 3-->
    <div class = "square" onclick="clicked(2,0)"></div>
    <!--Square 4-->
    <div class = "square" onclick="clicked(3,0)"></div>
</div>
<!--Row 2-->
<div class = "row">
    <!--Square 5-->
    <div class = "square" onclick="clicked(4,1)"></div>
    <!--Square 6-->
    <div class = "square" onclick="clicked(5,1)"></div>
    <!--Square 7-->
    <div class = "square" onclick="clicked(6,1)"></div>
    <!--Square 8-->
    <div class = "square" onclick="clicked(7,1)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're generating that HTML it would be efficient to add data-id attributes to the divs.

Comment: Note that Jonas answer will only work for your current html structure. Should you further decide to nest your squares within children rows or any other element, it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
const byClass = document.getElementsByClassName.bind(document);

if( byClass("row")[1] === byClass("square")[5].parentElement )
  alert("square[6] is in row[1]");
```

Just check if one is the parent of the other